# Plotting sorted data

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I would need to plot accounts through time, by sorting opening account.

I have the following two columns, one for the Accounts and one for OpenTime (it is datetime):

```
Account Name          OpenTime
ABC                 2002/05/20
BAB                 2012/07/24
CMN                 2012/07/24
GKS                 2001/12/05
EIR                 2018/04/21
```

I would like to see on the chart Account Names in the following order:

```
GKS    ABC     BAB,CMN      EIR
```

How can I get this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we need convert the date to datetime , then `sort_values`

```
df.OpenTime=pd.to_datetime(df.OpenTime)
df=df.sort_values('OpenTime')
print(df['Account Name'].tolist())
```

Comment: Thank you YOBEN_S. Yes, I already did it. But how could I plot this result?

Comment: I cannot see the Account names on the x_axis

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
plt.plot( da['Account Name'],da['OpenTime'], 'o-', linewidth=2)
```

does this answers plotting part?

Comment: The plot comes something like this https://imgur.com/a/7G3CiFo  , I have used continuous lines, u can use points too.